# RavenDb sharding behaviour when new server is added

Tags: ravendb

I have sharded my database to a couple of servers based on document id. Now I see the servers are overloaded and I want to add a new shard. As I guess by default RavenDb's round robbin algorithm will continue putting the equal amount of new document to each server.

Is there any way to make RavenDb put new documents to the new server till its performance becomes as low as the performance of two current servers? Resharding is a very undesirable option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can customize the shard resolution strategy to bias it toward the new servers.